# Is Linux protection mechanism implemented using capability lists?

Tags: access-control

I often get confused whether a particular protection mechanism is ACL or CL by definition. As an example to clarify this, I would like to consider the case of Linux.

I believe Linux uses `capability lists` to restrict non-root users from accessing everything. My explanation would be as follows:

- A `subject` in Linux system is a `user`: after logging in with your user name and password you become a particular subject of the CL. The subject is identified by its user-id or by one of the group-id the user belongs to. These ids are assigned to the user after the login is verified.
- A capability list for this particular subject is spread across the whole file system. Every file in the file system has a 9 bit flag of the form read/write/execute for UID, GID and others (+ extra SETUID flag which I will ignore for now). This 9 bit flag corresponds to `one capability entry` in the capability list.
- When a subject (user) wants to operate (e.g. read) on an object (file), the system works as follows:

  1. Check whether the user-id matches the file UID. If no, go to part 2, else check whether the read flag of file UID is high. If yes, allow the user to read a file, otherwise not.
  2. Check whether one of the user group-ids match the file GID. If any match is found, proceed analogously to part 1, else go to part 3.
  3. Case when the current user belongs to `others` class. Check whether read flag of others is high. If yes, allow the user to read a file, otherwise not.

**Is this explanation of Linux protection system correct?** If no, what is wrong with such explanation?

Comment: Users can be in multiple groups so step 2 needs iteration.

Comment: @Neil Smithline Not sure what you mean by iteration: iteration over what? Every file has only 3 "groups" associated with it: owner, owner's group, others. Don't see a point to iterate over 3 things only. And also, my main question was, why such explanation of Linux protection implementation using **capability lists** is not appropriate, as any other article I read claims that Linux uses ACL.

Comment: For file access, you need to compare file group id to *every* group the user is in. It is not a single comparison as you stated. And yes, I agree that it is ancillary to your main question.

Comment: Hmm, ok I see, I will modify the description a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on the filesystem in use.

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acl.5.html and the related manpages.